# event.persist is not a function - JEST & Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am using React 16.3 with JEST and Enzyme as my test utilities, I have an input where when user enters the email and blur the field, a function (handleInputBlur) gets called. In that function I am updating the state (setState) and `setState()` callback, I am calling another function and pass the event that was passed to `handleInputBlur` initially.

Now as I understand, since `setState` is async React does not allow to pass the event in callback of setState. so, I added `event.persist()` to persist the event. Everything works well so far.

When I try to run the JEST test case that I have written and simulate the `blur` on the input it calles the function but throws the error :

```
TypeError: e.persist is not a function
```

I am not able understand what exactly is to be done to get around this issue.

Comment: Without looking at code, it is difficult to find the cause of your error. Please add code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you simulate the event , you can pass a mock event object to it like

```
wrapper.find('a').simulate('blur', { persist: jest.fn()});
```

Comment: Glad to have helped